# SQL Join where is its own alias

Tags: sql

```
Select IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO As "Item #",
       IM_BARCOD.BARCOD AS "Barcode",
       IM_INV.MIN_QTY AS "Min Qty"
FROM IM_ITEM 
INNER JOIN IM_INV ON IM_INV.ITEM_NO = IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO
INNER JOIN IM_BARCOD ON IM_BARCOD.ITEM_NO = IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO  
where IM_BARCOD.BARCOD_ID ='BIN#'  
or IM_BARCOD.BARCOD_ID ='ITEM' 
or IM_BARCOD.BARCOD_ID ='ALT1'
ORDER BY IM_ITEM.CATEG_SUBCAT ASC, IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO ASC;
```

This works great for me however it repeats the part number for every row there is more than one barcode. I want the different barcodes in their own column instead of having to duplicate the part number on every row there is a different barcode. ever better would be if it selected all barcodes and put them in their own column for that part number. Thanks for the help I am very new to any type of coding!

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) This includes sample data and the output you would like to obtain from that data.

Comment: I believe what you're attempting to do is called "PIVOT" and is best performed in the User interface not the database.